# Change background of toggle button when it is pressed

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I see there is already some questions on this matter, but they are not using unity3d or are using the old UI method of unity.

I have a toggle button with a specific background and I want that background to change when the toggle is off. I tried to do this using the inspector and setting a function to apply a different texture to the button when it was off, but did not work.

Do you have any idea on how to accomplish this? I am attaching what I tried.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The background of a toggle is just an `Image`

so it's this simple,  in a script have

```
public Image theBackground;
```

you can then change that in any way you wish!

if you wish, have a function

```
public Image theBackground;
public Toggle theToggle;
 public void ChangeBackground()
  {
  if (theToggle.isOn)
      ... set theBackground as you wish ..
  else
      ... set theBackground as you wish ..
  }
```

which sets it appropriately.  Look in the toggle and drag that function to the OnValueChanged.

Enjoy!

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into the same problem. What I did to solve it was the following:

When you place the Toggle on the Hierarchy, you get

- Toggle

  - Background

    - Checkmark
  - Label

What I believe the toggle script does is modify the checkmark object (to make it appear or not).

So I replaced the Checkmark components (Rect Transform and Image (Script)) with the Background components.

Basically, just **Copy component > Paste component values** from **Background** to **Checkmark**.

And then, switch the Image Colors for both to the desired colors. Now when you Toggle in-game, you'll see it changes colors.

I know it's been a really long time, but it might help others :)