# How can I make a button to act like a toggle or maybe using a toggle and make the toggle to looks like a button?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class GenerateUIButtons : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Button buttonPrefab;
    public GameObject parent;
    public int numberOfButtons;
    public float spaceBetweenButtons;

    private Button[] buttons;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        buttons = new Button[Rotate.names.Length];

        for (int i = 0; i < buttons.Length; i++)
        {
            buttons[i] = Instantiate(buttonPrefab) as Button;
            buttons[i].name = Rotate.names[i];
            buttons[i].transform.SetParent(parent.transform, false);
            int j = i;
            buttons[i].onClick.AddListener(() => ButtonClicked(j));
        }
    }

    void ButtonClicked(int buttonNo)
    {
        Debug.Log("Clicked On " + buttons[buttonNo]);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }
}
```

I want that inside the ButtonClicked when clicking on a button the text inside color will change to green and stay green for the clicked button. And if clicking on the same green button again change the color back to the original.

Like a switch.

Comment: You can change button backgrounds in c# by using SolidColorBrush. E.G.: `Button.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);`

Comment: Use `Toggle` components, set the prefab's `Graphic` to `None` to remove the checkbox, then follow the instructions here: [Change background of toggle button when it is pressed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35853400/change-background-of-toggle-button-when-it-is-pressed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a custom one few days ago, take a look on the code below.

Here you can see it in action: https://youtu.be/sl9EheTbmhE

**ToggleButton.cs**

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Events;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
using UnityEngine.UI;

[RequireComponent(typeof(Image))]
public class ToggleButton : MonoBehaviour, IPointerClickHandler
{
    public ToggleEvent CheckedChanged = new ToggleEvent();

    Image _image;
    Color _originalColor;

    bool _checked;
    [SerializeField] Color _checkedColor;
    [SerializeField] ToggleButtonGroup _group;


    [SerializeField]
    public bool Checked
    {
        get
        {
            return _checked;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_checked != value)
            {
                _checked = value;
                UpdateVisual();
                CheckedChanged.Invoke(this);
            }
        }
    }

    void Start()
    {
        _image = GetComponent<Image>();
        _originalColor = _image.color;

        if (_group != null)
            _group.RegisterToggle(this);
    }

    private void UpdateVisual()
    {
        _image.color = Checked ? _checkedColor : _originalColor;
    }

    public void OnPointerClick(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        Checked = !Checked;
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class ToggleEvent : UnityEvent<ToggleButton>
    {
    }
}
```

**ToggleButtonGroup.cs**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ToggleButtonGroup : MonoBehaviour
{
    List<ToggleButton> _toggles = new List<ToggleButton>();

    public void RegisterToggle(ToggleButton toggle)
    {
        _toggles.Add(toggle);
        toggle.CheckedChanged.AddListener(HandleCheckedChanged);
    }

    void HandleCheckedChanged(ToggleButton toggle)
    {
        if (toggle.Checked)
        {
            foreach (var item in _toggles)
            {
                if (item.GetInstanceID() != toggle.GetInstanceID())
                {
                    item.Checked = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I like your solution. In the end I did my own script without any classes : https://pastebin.com/A5RLrUf8 And it's working fine. A bit messed. I'm using two lists for the colors. It's better to use classes and more scripts but I wanted to test it with one script.